# @Get DTO with multiple parameters in NestJs

Tags: nestjs

I'm trying to create a controller action in NestJS accessible via GET HTTP request which receives two params but they are undefined for some reason.

How to fix it?

```ts
@Get('/login')
login(@Param() params: LoginUserDto) {
  console.log(params)
  return 'OK'
}
```

```ts
import { ApiModelProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';

export class LoginUserDto {
  @ApiModelProperty()
  readonly userName: string;

  @ApiModelProperty()
  readonly password: string;
}
```

Answer (score 28):

In Browser

```
localhost:3001/Products/v1/user2
```

Controller like this:

```ts
@Controller('Products')
export class CrashesController {
  constructor(private readonly crashesService: CrashesService) { }

  @Get('/:version/:user')
  async findVersionUser(@Param('version') version: string, @Param('user') user: string): Promise<Crash[]> {
    return this.crashesService.findVersionUser(version, user);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Nest doesn't support the ability to automatically convert `Get` query params into an object in this way. It's expected that you would pull out the params individually by passing the name of the param to the `@Param` decorator.

Try changing your signature to:

```
login(@Param('userName') userName: string, @Param('password') password: string)
```

If you want to receive an object instead consider switching to using `Post` and passing the object in the request body (which makes more sense to me for a login action anyways).

Comment: Do you know if it continues to be this way?

Answer (score 6):

Right now I am using nestJs on 7.0.0 and if you do this:

```js
@Get('/paramsTest3/:number/:name/:age')
  getIdTest3(@Param() params:number): string{
    console.log(params);
    return this.appService.getMultipleParams(params);
  }
```

The `console.log(params)` result will be(the values are only examples):

```json
{ number:11, name: thiago, age: 23 }
```

Comment: Would there be a way to make one of these parameters optional? For instance: `@Get('/paramsTest3/:number/:name/:age?')`

Comment: @MichaelLRhyndress I would use a JSON body if you want to do this

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you need to pass one required parameter named `id`. You can send it through `header params`, and your optional parameters can be sent via `query params`:

```js
@Get('/:id')
findAll(
    @Param('id') patientId: string,
    @Query() filter: string,
): string {
    console.log(id);
    console.log(filter);

    return 'Get all samples';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
@Get('/login/:email/:password')
@ApiParam({name:'email',type:'string'})
@ApiParam({name:'password',type:'string'})
login(@Param() params: string[]) {
    console.log(params)
    return 'OK'
}
```

Output

```json
{email:<input email >,password:<input password>}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get multiple params and map them to your dto in this way:

```js
    @Get('/login')
    login(@Param() { userName, password }: LoginUserDto) {
    console.log({ userName});
    console.log({ password });
    return 'OK'
    }
```