# How to make update function in NestJS/Prisma for an id with multiple fields?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, nest, prisma

I made this table answer using Prisma but I'm struggling to define an update function because the ID is made of two foreign keys from tables user and question.

Here's what I've done so far:

- schema.prisma

```
model Answer{
  id_question Int
  id_user String
  content String @db.VarChar(250)
  updated_at DateTime @updatedAt
  user User @relation(fields: [id_user], references: [id])
  question Question @relation(fields: [id_question], references: [id])
  @@id([id_question, id_user], name:"question_user")
}
```

- answers.service.ts

```
 async updateAnswer(params: {
    where: Prisma.AnswerWhereUniqueInput;
    data: Prisma.AnswerUpdateInput;
  }): Promise<Answer> {
    const { where, data } = params;
    return this.prisma.answer.update({
      data,
      where,
    });
  }
```

- answers.controller.ts

Here's where I don't know how to define the route and define the id parameter

```
@Patch('answer/:id')
  async updateAnswer(@Param('id') id: string): Promise<answerModel> {
    return this.postService.updateAnswer({
      where: { id: Number(id) },
      data: { content: true },
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As the model `Answer` had an id combined of two fields, i.e. `id_question` and `id_user`, you would need to pass both the values in the where clause.

So in the `answers.service.ts` file, the where clause should look like this:

```js
 async updateAnswer(params: {
    where: Prisma.AnswerWhereUniqueInput;
    data: Prisma.AnswerUpdateInput;
  }): Promise<Answer> {
    const { where, data } = params;
    return this.prisma.answer.answer.update({
    where: {
      question_user: {
        id_question: 1, \\ the id_question value
        id_user: '1', \\ the id_user value
      },
    },
    data: {},
  });
  }
```

And to pass multiple parameters in the controller you can refer this Stack Overflow [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422432/get-dto-with-multiple-parameters-in-nestjs).